# jQuery UI draggable locking divs

Tags: jquery-ui

I wrote some kind of that: http://jsfiddle.net/py3DE/203/ but when element is dragged into proper container, we can override it by dragging other div into its area. Could you tel me how i can block dragged elements, and if someone will try to override any element, div returns back into area with undragged divs?

```
if (!ui.draggable.closest('.empty').length) item = item.draggable()'
```

Comment: I would think that `sortable()` might be a better option than `droppable()`. To clarify, if a slot in `.target` is filled, you want the dragged item to be reverted?

Comment: Exactly, and it will be possible to change position the `.item` in `.target`

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to do this. Basically, we'll remove the class `empty` and use the `disable` method.

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/5rdxmp4p/

**Minor CSS Change**

```
.filled .item .closer {
  display: block;
}
```

**Drop Function**

```
  drop: function(ev, ui) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("empty")) {
      $(this).removeClass("empty").addClass("filled");
      $(this).droppable("disable");
    } else {
      return false;
    }
    var item = ui.draggable;
    if (!ui.draggable.closest('.empty').length) item = item.draggable(); // if item was dragged from the source list - clone it
    this.innerHTML = ''; // clean the placeholder
    item.css({
      top: 0,
      left: 0
    }).appendTo(this); // append item to placeholder
  }
```

Swapping the class allows the `X` button to appear. We then run the `disable` method to ensure that this specific item will no longer accept a dragged item. If the user drags an item to this spot, it is then reverted.

**Update**

Using Sortable: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/5rdxmp4p/2/

**HTML**

```
<div id="dragItems" class="source">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item">Item 5</div>
</div>
<div id="sortItems" class="target">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  background: #fff;
}

.source,
.target {
  margin: 20px;
  min-height: 190px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.target {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.item {
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: #cd8;
  position: relative;
}

.closer {
  float: right;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.closer:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
}

.empty {
  height: 30px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px dashed #999;
}

.highlight {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: #fff;
}

.highlight .item {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.ui-draggable-dragging {
  z-index: 99;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  width: 378px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  $("#sortItems").sortable({
    axis: "y",
    items: "> div",
    placeholder: "empty",
    dropOnEmpty: true,
    stop: function(e, ui) {
      var $it = ui.item;
      if ($it.find(".closer").length == 0) {
        var closeBtn = $("<span>", {
          class: "closer"
        });
        $it.append(closeBtn);
        closeBtn.button({
          icon: "ui-icon-close",
          label: "Close",
          showLabel: false
        }).click(function(ev) {
          console.log("[INFO]: Closing ", $it);
          $it.fadeTo(200, 0.0, function() {
            $it.remove();
            $("#sortItems").sortable("refresh");
          });
        });
      }
    }
  });

  $("#dragItems .item").draggable({
    connectToSortable: "#sortItems",
    revert: "invalid"
  });

  $("#sortItems").disableSelection();
});
```

Comment: but if you click x button, element will disapper and space, where element was placed also will disappear. My target is to remove x button, but when i change element position, but in this case space, where element was placed also will disappear...

Comment: @jdoe your original question did not address these issues. I saw them, and some others, but did not address them as they were not in the scope of your post. Hence my comment regarding `sortable()` as a better potential solution. But I did not want to assume.

Comment: ok, but for me it was clear, i understand you. Can you help me and show how to do it?

Comment: @jdoe Updated my answer. This is simply to show you a proof of concept. In the future, I would give something a stab first. "Can you help me" was more like, would you write this code for me.